# How to get Windows 10 Ent to prompt for Enterprise login by default during setup?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, media-creation-tool

*Before marking as a duplicate, I understand that I can set up Windows using a local/Microsoft account, then link up to a domain, but I'd like to avoid a local/MS account if possible.  Microsoft indicates this* should *be possible*

I have Windows 10 Enterprise installed on my laptop.  I created a USB boot disk for re-installation, using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10), and have proceeded to format the machine and re-install.

During set up, the machine now asks me to log in using a Microsoft Account.  The main reason for my re-install was to move away from Microsoft Account usage, and instead use my Office365/AzureAD account.

Upon investigation (including various blog/QA sites), [Microsoft says](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/devices/azuread-joined-devices-frx):

> If you have either Windows 10 Professional or Windows 10 Enterprise
>   installed on a device, the experience defaults to the setup process
>   for company-owned devices.
>
> In the Windows out-of-box experience, joining an on-premises Active
>   Directory (AD) domain is not supported. If you plan to join a computer
>   to an AD domain, during setup, you should select the link Set up
>   Windows with a local account. You can then join the domain from the
>   settings on your computer.

1. What is the opposite of my *out-of-box* approach (as covered by their first sentence)?  How do you get Windows onto a device via a different method?  Should I use that alternative method instead of my existing approach?
2. At the risk of ranting... Why doesn't Microsoft's initial log in page provide the option to specify the device's owner (e.g. my organisation) on ALL versions?

#### Update

Since posting this question, I've also tried [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and Win10Ent, but the result is the same - no mention of the device owner during initial set up.

Comment: Joining a domain requires a domain account with appropriate permissions. If you want to automate this process in a secure manner, I suggest looking into SCCM. Though I’m not sure this would be of any use for Azure AD. Office 365 isn’t Azure AD, by the way.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked into SCCM (with Intune), but I need a Premium AD subscription which is a bit beyond requirements at the minute.  I was hoping for a quick workaround on this but I don't think there is one sadly...

Comment: Unfortunately, this can't really be done.  Even an [advanced Windows deployment solution that utilizes WDS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jletsch/2017/11/15/lets-build-a-standalone-deployment-server/) to automate the process will still login with a local account before it joins the domain.  That being said, we are always glad to help but a question of this nature would probably be more appropriate within the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) community.

Comment: It's by default design that when you're not configuring the computer to be in a domain to upon deployment that the OOBE will prompt you to login with local account or MS account. The oppsite of th OOBE? Do you mean skip of OOBE? We need to configure unattend.xml file to skip.